# issue with fileUpload in MVC if site.master contains <scriptmanager>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

iam working on fileUpload in mvc.
my code is as follows:

Views/Client/AddClient.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Auditz.UI.Web.Automation.ClientService.ClientDto>" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h1>
    Add A Client</h1>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddClient","Client",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div class="tabcontrol">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlClientDtls" runat="server">
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="1">
            <asp:TabPanel ID="tb1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Client Details
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="formelements">
                    .....................
                     ..............
                      </div>
```

Controllers/FileUploadController.cs

```
 namespace FileUploadTest.Controllers
 {
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /FileUpload/

    public ActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

Evrything works as desired with this code.
But if i place  and  in  of Shared/Site.Master,iam getting null value in "HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile".

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
<div>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

i cannot remove  from my code as i want to add few ajax controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you don't nest HTML forms. So in your Master page when you open the `<form>` tag ensure that you close it before rendering the view:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>

    ...

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

</body>
```

Comment: "Control 'MainContent_TabContainer' of type 'TabContainer' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."                                   This the error iam getting if i close form tag before rendring view

Comment: Congratulations @Darin: https://twitter.com/#!/marcgravell/status/179944638772281344

Comment: @Santosh, you need to place this control inside the form with `runat="server"`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov edited my code in the above question(ignore controller code as it is irrelevant).look at the Site.Master .Iam placing like that.evn now iam getting error.

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot use `<asp:` controls outside of a form that doesn't have the runat="server" attribute. In fact you shouldn't be using such controls at all in ASP.NET MVC. Most of them rely on viewstate and postbacks and won't work as expected. I think that you will have lots of troubles with this scenario. Good luck.